# Pandemic Special Orders

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

Can player A play the Special Orders card during player B's turn, allowing B to then move the character of A or some third party C, or can it only be used on player A's turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [this other question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/how-does-the-special-orders-special-event-card-work), although it is a distinct question so no need to merge.

The Special orders card says "Play at any time." which seems pretty clear to me. Whoever has the event card can play it on any player's turn. Then, the player whose turn it is can use their actions as normal, or to move the piece of one other player. So if A plays it on B's turn, then B may choose A or C, and move that player's piece as if it were B's.